# How to convert an H2 datadump to SQLSever datadump

Tags: sql-server-2008, h2

I have an H2 database backup file (backup.sql). Now I need to modify this dumpfile to support SQL Server 2008. 
Is it possible to do?

Comment: That sounds cool. Whenever you come up with/ find a **specific** problem, come on back and we can answer it! Unfortunately we don't just write the code for you here!,

Comment: A short answer to the question is: Yes, it is possible to do that. For a long answer, you would need to provide more details.

Comment: I have a database in H2 Dbms. I generated the Sql script for the database. Now I need to convert this database into Sql Server. What are the needful steps to modify such that it supports Sql Server